# Authentication and Access Salesforce Account through Other Portals

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, oauth2, oauth

I am developing an application in Angularjs and my requirements is to get login in my application through SalesForce, and access data of SalesForce.

I have created developer account in Salesforce and made application and have consumer key, consumer secret.

As of Now, I have understood things in this way,

- Created a Developer SalesForce Account
- Have Consumer Secret, and Consumer key

For the moment, I have button, and on click button, window is getting opened through this code..

```
    var authUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?' + $.param({
                client_id : $scope.salesforce_clientId_web,
                redirect_uri : $scope.salesforce_client_redirecturi,
                response_type : $scope.salesforce_response_type
            });
    var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

- First Time It will ask me for login in salesforce and it will redirect on redirect_uril which is given in my code..and I wll get code = "2323223".

  - I will fetch the code and will again do http post request using this code to get Request token, which helps me to get access of Salesforce account.

but, Now I have question Is there any api or javascript file which provide above steps like google has

```
<script src="scripts/google_client.js"></script>
```

It automatically pop-up window for google authentication. so, is there anything for salesforce.

Before I come on to any conclusion, and start implementing my code, I want to make sure. what is possible in salesforce.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unaware of an officially provided solution like google_client.js, but it sounds like you have implemented the correct steps for a User-Agent OAuth2.0 flow. http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US

There are libraries that the community has provided, such as nforce (https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce), a nodejs module that is a REST wrapper for Salesforce which includes authentication logic, and this blog post about using username/password OAuth flow in python http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/11/forcecom-token-requests-with-python/. There are other libraries and blogs out there if you are looking for a different options.

Detailed OAuth2.0 Force.com information: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com.